# Lua converting my identifier to a string when I put it into a table?

Tags: lua, identifier

```
a = {}
b = "s"
a.b = "white"
a["s"] = 2
local keyset={}
local n=0

for k,v in pairs(a) do
    n=n+1
    keyset[n]=k
    print(type(k))
-- output is String(x2)
end
```

Does Lua recognize b as a string and not as an identifier if I do a.b?

Answer (score 2):

From the Lua Documentation:

> A common mistake for beginners is to confuse a.x with a[x]. The first form represents a["x"], that is, a table indexed by the string "x". The second form is a table indexed by the value of the variable x.

If anyone would like to add on to why Lua does this, feel free to do it! The question is however answered at this point.

**UPD** Before the for loop, `a = {['b'] = 'white', ['s'] = 2}`.

Comment: is not it obvious?

Comment: No. In some languages you have to explicitly tell the program what a String is for it to parse something as a string using quotemarks without exception. This was the first time I've seen this, so I as confused at first.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the keyset table;  that's not converting anything.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

a = {}
b = "s"  --  completely different variable, not used in a

a.b = "white"  --  syntactic sugar for  a["b"] = "white"
a["s"] = 2  --  variable b just happens to have same value as this key, so it fits

--  at this point there are two entries in a
--  a["b"] = "white"   and   a["s"] = 2

for k, v in pairs( a ) do
    print( 'key:', k, type(k), '  val:', v, type(v) )
end

print( b, a[b] )  --  retrieve value from  a["s"]  coincidental key fit
```

key:    s   string    val:  2       number
key:    b   string    val:  white   string
s       2